# How do I test a function within a React hook, but that inner function returns based on the output of a promise

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, jestjs

I have a hook that I want to test that looks something like this:

```
export useFunc(){
  const func = async () => {
    const [result, otherStuff] = await Promise.all([getSomeData(), someOtherStuff()])
      
    if (!result){
       return; // I NEED TO TEST THIS
    }
    return result;
  }
  return { func };
}
```

The test is set up like so:

```
it("whatever description", () => {

  const { result } = renderHook(() => useFunc());
  const { func } = result.current;
  
  // I need to somehow test that the return gets hit inside `func`!
  
});
```

How do I go about testing this return statement?

Comment: Is the inner function imported into this module?

Comment: It is not being imported, I forgot to mention that I'm testing a hook here.  Will update!  Thanks @Harry!

Comment: Just call the `func` from the test and verify you get null or whatever. Also you're not awaiting `Promise.all` so the test is always going to return null. 

I'd say: write a test for the success case, make that pass. Once passing, the second test should assert the returned value is empty. If it's not, you know you didn't get into your `if` block

Comment: Woops missed the await on the `Promise.all` when I copied this over, just updated it!  Thanks for catching that!  Will try this out, thanks @Tom

Comment: What does `getSomeData` return? Also, why are you using `Promise.all` if you only have one thing you're waiting for? Just await _that_? `const result = await getSomeData();`.

Comment: `getSomeData` just returns a dictionary in this case, but I believe I can mock it to be any falsy value.  Updated the code to reflect that I am actually using a `Promise.all` for other stuff too. Thanks!

Comment: object, rather, not dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay something like this works, as easy as just calling the function like Tom mentioned!

```
it("whatever description", async () => {
  mockGetSomeData.mockResolvedValueOnce(undefined) // just need to make sure this is mocked properly
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useFunc());
  const { func } = result.current;
  
  const returnedValue = await func();
  
  expect(returnedValue).toBe(undefined);
});
```